# Can I keep apple appstore revenue with apple for longer time?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-store

I would like to know weather I can keep my appstore revenue with apple and withdraw whenever I like..?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will not lose the revenue from not withdrawing it. It will stay against your account as long as your account remains active.

Comment: Mitch, I have a couple of apps in appstore, apple sends the full money every month..how to tell them to send only a part of it and keep the rest with them..?